# I get error message Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript

```
function printFarmInventory(monkeys, cats) {
    var monkeystring = String(monkeys);
    while (monkeystring.length < 3) {
        monkeystring = "0" + monkeystring;
    }

    console.log(monkeystring + "nice");

    var catstring = String(cat);
    while (catstring.length < 3) {
        chimpstring = "00" + catstring;
    }

    console.log(catstring + "great");
}

printFarmInventory(4, 7);
```

Comment: What's `cat` in `String(cat);`? I also sense an infinite loop there.

Comment: The error message will tell you what you are trying to reference. Check that variable name and make sure it is something you have defined. Look for typos. (Typo is obvious, voting to close as off-topic)

Comment: Where does `chimpstring` come from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the context.

Changing `String(cat)` to `String(cats)` and changing `chimpstring = ...` to `catstring = ...` resolves the error and get your output as expected. Edit your question if I missed the mark.

```js
function printFarmInventory(monkeys, cats) {
  var monkeystring = String(monkeys);
  while (monkeystring.length < 3) {
    monkeystring = "0" + monkeystring;
  }

  console.log(monkeystring + "nice");

  var catstring = String(cats);
  while (catstring.length < 3) {
    catstring = "00" + catstring;
  }
  console.log(catstring + "great");
}
printFarmInventory(4, 7);
```